# Misplaced accent in ec-lmr10

Tags: fonts, accents, font-encodings, latin-modern

In plain TeX, `\ddot{a}` places the double-dot accent correctly above the letter `a`. However, if I (attempt to) switch from the default (Computer Modern) fonts to `ec-lmr10` (I believe that this is Latin Modern?), the double dot accent ends up in the middle of `a`.

Running `pdftex` on the code below gives me two correct "double-dotted a", two correct "vectored a", then two wrong "double-dotted a" and two correct "vectored a", so the problem depends on the accent.

```
$\ddot{a}\mathaccent"707F{a}$
$\vec{a} \mathaccent"017E{a}$
\font\tenrm = ec-lmr10 at 10pt\relax
\textfont0 = \tenrm
$\ddot{a}\mathaccent"707F{a}$
$\vec{a} \mathaccent"017E{a}$
\bye
```

Two questions: What is causing the diffference? (Some fontdimen parameter, perhaps?) And what am I doing wrong, how could I fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The font `ec-lmr10` is T1-encoded, not OT1. So at position `"7F` it hasn't the dieresis.

With `\mathaccent"7004` you get the right accent.